# Installing Ububtu 12.04 on Dell Inspiron N5110 already having 3 active partitions

Tags: 12.04, installation, dell, swap, inspiron

The Dell Inspiron N5110 already has 3 active partitions - 
BOOT FAT 32 (44 MB for Dell Diagnostic tools)
RECOVERY NTFS (15 GB)
SYSTEM (192 GB )

Option 1 :-I can shrink the system volume and install Ubuntu but i would like to have SNAP partition too which is not possible because of maximum limit of 4 active partitions.

Is it safe to copy recovery partition and then add the space to SYSTEM. I can then shrink SYSTEM to make 16 GB space. Then make 6 GB swap and 10 GB for Ununtu.

Option 2 :- Use Install Ubuntu side by side option and let Ubuntu decide (I am bit wary to let ubuntu habdle this process)

Also is it possible to install Ubuntu in extended partition and then create a logical swap, Is there any performance difference between Logical and Active Swap ?
Install Ubuntu side by side Windows 7 - Does this option create SWAP if yes then is it Active or Logical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no performance difference between primary and logical partitions.  The side by side option should automatically use the 4th primary partition for an extended, and create logical partitions inside for the filesystem and swap.  6 GB of swap is a bit overkill though, especially with such a limited space, so I would suggest skipping the swap entirely, or at least limiting it to 2 GB.

Comment: Ok Thanks ! so side by side option is better, can you suggest how to install logical swap partition after ubuntu installation. The reason i was interested in SWAP was because i heard that swap should be 1.5 times RAM and i have 4GB ram. I want to use hibernate and sleep option also , in terms of applications i will not be using just for browsing reading and VOIP.

Comment: @user193714, you can use `gparted` on the livecd to manipulate the partitions on the disk, but if you used up the 4th primary partition already installing Ubuntu ( and it wasn't used to create an extended partition ), then you'll have to delete it and start over.